# How to update quantity of product in the cart and display total amount in cart page on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now, Im doing shopping cart project and met some questions that I don't know 
how to pass value from view to model in ruby on rails. 
all coding is here => https://github.com/Gtar69/artstore_hw2

My idea is that I want to input quantity in the view/carts/index.html
and pass quantity vars to model/carts.rb to do some simple calculation to render 
total_price in the cart... but I don't have idea how to do that!

Very Thanks !!!

in view/carts/index.html

```
<tbody>


 <% current_cart.items.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
          <td><%= render_product_photo(product.default_photo) %></td>


        <td> 
          <%= link_to(product.title, admin_product_path(product)) %>
        </td>
        <td> <%= product.price %> </td>
        <td><input type="number" name= product.id  value="1"/></td> 
        <td><%= link_to("刪除物品",  delete_item_carts_path(:product_id => product.id) , :method => :post , :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger") %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="total group">
    <span class="pull-right">
       <span> 總計 <%= render_cart_total_price(current_cart) %> NTD  
    </span>
  </div>


  <div class = "checkout">
      <%= link_to("刪除全部", delete_all_carts_path,:method => :post, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger pull-left") %>
  </div>

  <div class="checkout">
      <%= link_to("確認結賬", "#" , :method => :post , :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger pull-right") %>
  </div>
```

in carts.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cart_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :items, :through => :cart_items, :source => :product


  def add_product_to_cart(product)
    items << product
    # cart_items和product
  end

  def remove_product_from_cart(product)
    items.destroy(product)
    #cart_items.where(:product_id => product.id).destroy_all 
  end  

  def remove_all_products_in_cart
    items.destroy_all 
    #clear => destory_all
  end  

  def total_price
    items.inject(0){|sum, item| sum +item.price}
  end  

end
```

in carts_helper

```
module CartsHelper
  def cart_items_count(cart)
    cart.cart_items.count
  end  

  def render_cart_total_price(current_cart)
    current_cart.total_price
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't suggest using the function in the helper.

Secondly, in your view:

```
<div class="total group">
    <span class="pull-right">
       <span> 總計 <%= current_cart.total_price %> NTD  
    </span>
```

Your model:

```
def total_price
   self.items.pluck(:price).inject(:+)
end
```

Pluck will return an array from the price column and the inject adds all the elements in the array.

Hope that works!